# Increase the length of text returned by Highlighter

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, highlight

Initially, I thought `setMaxDocCharsToAnalyze(int)` will increase the output length, but it does not.

Currently the output generated by my Search (`String fragment`) is less than a line long and hence makes no sense as a *preview*.

Can the output generated by `getBestFragment()` be increased, by some mechanism, to at least 1 sentence or more (it does not matter if it is one and a half sentences or more, but I need it to be long enough to at least make *some* sense).

#### Indexing:

```java
Document document = new Document();
document.add(new TextField(FIELD_CONTENT, content, Field.Store.YES));
document.add(new StringField(FIELD_PATH, path, Field.Store.YES));
indexWriter.addDocument(document);
```

#### Searching

```java
QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(FIELD_CONTENT, new StandardAnalyzer());
Query query = queryParser.parse(searchQuery);
QueryScorer queryScorer = new QueryScorer(query, FIELD_CONTENT);
Fragmenter fragmenter = new SimpleSpanFragmenter(queryScorer);

Highlighter highlighter = new Highlighter(queryScorer); // Set the best scorer fragments
highlighter.setMaxDocCharsToAnalyze(100000); //"HAS NO EFFECT"
highlighter.setTextFragmenter(fragmenter); 

// STEP B
File indexFile = new File(INDEX_DIRECTORY);
Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(indexFile.toPath());
IndexReader indexReader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);

// STEP C
System.out.println("query: " + query);
ScoreDoc scoreDocs[] = searcher.search(query, MAX_DOC).scoreDocs;
for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : scoreDocs)
{
    //System.out.println("1");
    Document document = searcher.getDocument(scoreDoc.doc);
    String title = document.get(FIELD_CONTENT);
    TokenStream tokenStream = TokenSources.getAnyTokenStream(indexReader,
                    scoreDoc.doc, FIELD_CONTENT, document, new StandardAnalyzer());
    String fragment = highlighter.getBestFragment(tokenStream, title); //Increase the length of the this String this is the output
    System.out.println(fragment + "-------");
 }
```

#### Sample Output

> query: +Content:canada +Content:minister
>   |Liberal]] [[Prime **Minister** of **Canada**|Prime **Minister**]] [[Pierre Trudeau]] led a  [[Minority-------
>   . Thorson, **Minister** of National War Services, Ottawa. Printed in **Canada**       Description: British lion-------
>    politician of the [[New Zealand Labour Party| Labour Party]], and a cabinet **minister**.       He represented-------
>   |}}}|    ! [[**Minister** of Finance (**Canada**)|**Minister**]]    {{!}} {{{**minister**-------
>   , District of Franklin''. Ottawa: **Minister** of Supply and Services **Canada**, 1977. ISBN 0660008351   
>    25]], [[1880]] – [[March 4]], [[1975]]) was a [[**Canada**|Canadian]] provincial and federal-------
>   -du-Quebec]] region, in [[**Canada**]]. It is named after the first French Canadian to become Prime-------
>   11569347, Cannon_family_(**Canada**) ::: {{for|the American political family|Cannon family-------
>    **minister** of [[Guyana]] and prominent Hindu politician in [[Guyana]]. He also served, at various times-------
>   11559743, Mohammed_Hussein_Al_Shaali ::: '''Mohammed Hussein Al Shaali''' is the former **Minister**-------

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Fragmenter` is the piece that controls this behavior.  You can pass an `int` into the `SimpleSpanFragmenter` constructor to control the size of the fragments it produces (in bytes).  The default size is 100.  For example, to double that:

```
Fragmenter fragmenter = new SimpleSpanFragmenter(queryScorer, 200);
```

As far as splitting on sentence boundaries, there isn't a fragmenter for that, out of the box.  Someone posted their [implementation of one here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-dev/200801.mbox/%3C14690255.post@talk.nabble.com%3E).  It's an **extremely naive** implementation, but you may find it helpful if you want to go down that particular rabbit hole.